Mostrar modal onmouseover en bootstrap 4.6
Estoy haciendo un sitio para un simposio, y tengo una sección con los ponentes.
En una "card" se muestra la foto y el nombre del ponente.
Tengo un "card footer" con un + que al picarla aparece el modal.
Quiero que el modal aparezca al pasar el cursor sobre la +, y no lo logro.
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-img"><img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="img/Rafael-Vazquez-Duhalt_inf.png" alt=""></div>
            <h5 class="card-title">Dr. Rafael Vázquez Duhalt</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Centro de Nanociencias y Nanotecnología CNYN, Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México, Ensenada</p>
            <div class="card-footer"><a href="#Duhalt" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Duhalt" onmouseover="triggerModal()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

También lo intenté con un <script>


<script>$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myModal").hover(function () {
  var modalId = $(this).data('target');
  $(modalId).modal('show');

  });

});</script>


